# Trying to query a database of a hotel to return the id of the unoccupied rooms on a specific date on SQLZOO

Tags: sql

The question I'm trying to answer wants me to query the DB for:
List the rooms that are free on the day 25th Nov 2016.

This is what I have so far,

```
SELECT room_no FROM booking b
JOIN room ON b.room_no = room.id
WHERE booking_date = '2016-11-25' AND occupants IS NULL
```

I've modified it to:

```
SELECT room_no FROM booking b
JOIN room ON b.room_no = room.id
JOIN guest ON guest_id = guest.id
WHERE booking_date = '2016-11-25' AND guest_id IS NULL
```

And I'm still getting the table header with no values, when I should be getting room ids 207, 210, 304.

I'm sure I'm missing something but I just can't see what, any help is much appreciated.

https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Hard

Thanks :)

[image: UML Diagram]

Comment: `occupants IS NULL`!

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: *"Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL"* - Should be doable for this one.

Comment: SQLzoo has a strange naming convention. Use plural for table names (a table stores data about many items.) Use singular for column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your SQL query is not correct (you can check if `occupants IS NULL` but not compare them with the `=` operator), you are doing an **INNER JOIN**, which will only return rows matching in both tables.

Rooms without a booking for that day should not have a **booking** associated because nobody made a booking. You have to get the rooms that **do not have** a booking starting before Nov 25th or that date, and ending later than that.

You can get what you want with a subquery:

```
SELECT id FROM room 
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT room_no FROM booking
     WHERE (DATE_ADD(booking_date, INTERVAL nights DAY) > '2016-11-25'
            AND booking_date <= '2016-11-25'))
```

I assumed you are using MariaDB (therefore I used `DATE_ADD` function) as that is the DBMS that SQLZOO appears to be based on.

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking the number of nights into account, so the logic is more like this:

```
SELECT room_no
FROM room r LEFT JOIN
     booking b
     ON b.room_no = room.id AND
        '2016-11-25' < booking_date + interval nights day AND
        '2016-11-25' >= booking_date
WHERE b.room_no IS NULL;
```

Comment: That is not correct. Although it is syntactically incorrect (lack of an `AND` and `IS NULL` without the space) and uses wrong field names, you should be adding nights (not subtracting) and using `<` on your first expression and `>=` on the second one.